# How to run VBS code in a batch file?

Tags: batch, vbscript

I know the `cscript "filename.VBS"` command, but I want to run VBS code within a batch file so I will not have to make a VBS file to do it.

This is my VBS code:

```vbs
sub Loading
    do while brw.busy
        wscript.sleep 350
    loop
end sub

query=inputbox("Please Enter What You Would Like To Search:","Multi-Engine Internet Searcher")
'down-Google
set brw=CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
brw.navigate "https://www.google.ca/#q=" & (query)
brw.toolbar=false
brw.statusbar=true
brw.height=650
brw.width=950
brw.left=0
brw.top=0
brw.resizable=true
Call Loading
brw.visible=true
'up-google
'down-bing
```

Comment: Echo this code into `%temp%\filename.VBS` (random name recommended, or check this file not exists, do not forget to delete it after), then execute using `start /w`.

Comment: Why not do it all in **PowerShell**?

Comment: With all due respect Why not do it with batch script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a *hybrid VBS-batch* script. Put your VBS part between the `<job><script>` tags

```vbs
<!-- : Begin batch script
@echo off
cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf" %1
exit /b

----- Begin wsf script --->
<job><script language="VBScript">
sub Loading
    do while brw.busy
        wscript.sleep 350
    loop
end sub

query=inputbox("Please Enter What You Would Like To Search:","Multi-Engine Internet Searcher")
'down-Google
set brw=CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
brw.navigate "https://www.google.ca/#q=" & (query)
brw.toolbar=false
brw.statusbar=true
brw.height=650
brw.width=950
brw.left=0
brw.top=0
brw.resizable=true
Call Loading
brw.visible=true
'up-google
'down-bing
</script></job>
```

See [Is it possible to embed and execute VBScript within a batch file without using a temporary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9074476/995714)